# How to access folder near to my application in webapp?

Tags: java, servlets

my application is under wtpwebapps folder

```
wtpwebapps->myapp
```

and my files are under the wtpwebapps->files folder

```
wtpwebapps->files->file1
wtpwebapps->files->file2
wtpwebapps->files->file3
```

i've tried

```
request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath();
```

and got this path

```
workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
```

when i append

```
"\files\file1"
```

to the path and acces that files then it gives me error that

```
The requested resource is not available
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: did you try `"files\file1"` instead? this will make it a relative path

Comment: How are you trying to access the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the absolute path to your `myApp/WEB-INF/classes` directory as below:

```
URL resource = getClass().getResource("/");
String path = resource.getPath();
```

Now you can manipulate the `path` string to go to your files:

```
path = path.replace("your_app_name/WEB-INF/classes/", "");
path = path + "files/file1";
```

Here `path` is now referring to `file1` present in `wtpwebapps->files`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
File currentDir=new File(request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath())
// or try this instead too:
// File currentDir=new File(".");

File myFile=new File(currentDir,"files\\file1");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you append literally `\files\file1` this won´t work because backslash is the escape character. Try

```
/files/file1
```

Java will convert to the platform path seperator.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code from a listener ....

```
System.out.println("Inside contextInitialized()");

System.out.println( servletContextEvent.getServletContext().getRealPath("") );
System.out.println( servletContextEvent.getServletContext().getRealPath("/") );

String filePath  = servletContextEvent.getServletContext().getRealPath("/public/file.txt");
File file = new File(filePath);

System.out.println( filePath );
System.out.println( file.exists() );
```

and its output...

```
Inside contextInitialized()
C:\...\WS\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SampleWebApp
C:\...\WS\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SampleWebApp\
C:\...\WS\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SampleWebApp\public\file.txt
true
```

Note that i have edited the path in between.